What Does Conformal Prediction Add to Highly Accurate Models?
I have been studying Conformal Prediction (CP) for some time now. What I cannot get is, what CP can add to Machine Learning (ML) models that are already very accurate. Why would someone prefer to use CP on top of an ML model whose accuracy is over $95\%$? How can the prediction of such ML model be described as "heuristic"? In what sense does CP improve the ML model very "good" predictions?
Edit: As per a commenter request, the interested reader may refer to the following sources for in depth discussion of CP:

"Conformal Prediction" Advanced Topics in Statistical Learning, Spring 2023
Ryan Tibshirani
Angelopoulos, Anastasios N., and Stephen Bates. "A gentle introduction to conformal prediction and distribution-free uncertainty quantification." arXiv preprint arXiv:2107.07511 (2021).
Balasubramanian, Vineeth, Shen-Shyang Ho, and Vladimir Vovk, eds. Conformal prediction for reliable machine learning: theory, adaptations and applications. Newnes, 2014.

P.S. Please don't give me a crash course on CP as I already know the technicalities of it. I am just asking about the advantage it gives over highly accurate ML (e.g. classification) models.

Conformal prediction (CP) doesn't necessarily improve the model’s predictive accuracy which is an average metric for a test set, but as a Frequentist concept it improves reliability by quantifying distribution-free uncertainty for any specific prediction by creating prediction intervals (for regression) or sets (for classification) that's useful even for Bayesians. CP enhances the interpretation of the model’s output by adding more transparency and trustworthiness, especially when predictions are on the boundary of what the model is trained on or when new data is encountered in the out-of-distribution (OOD) cases.
For the example of a classifier model, the main trick is to first compute nonconformity scores for all labeled data in the calibration set after splitting the training data into the proper training set and the calibration set, which is a measure of how different each calibration point is from the model’s prediction confidence (e.g., probabilistic classifier's confidence output) or some other measure (e.g., error margin, distance from decision boundary, etc) and sort them.
Then you compute the p-value of each class label for any new unlabeled test data according to some formula involving its noncomformity score and all the calibration data's scores, and similar to standard Frequentist hypothesis testing, if the p-value of a label is greater than a chosen threshold (significance level in the CP field) then the label should be in the prediction. For example, for a significance level of 0.1 (with 90% confidence level), all labels with a p-value of 0.1 or greater are added to the prediction set since a p-value of 0.1 or higher means that the test data conforms to these included labels at least as well as the worst 10% of unconformity scores in the calibration set. Softmax probabilities output of a usual probabilistic classifier are heuristic since they depend on the model architecture, training method, and the proper training set, thus they don't guarantee statistical coverage. On the other hand, p-values are distribution-free thus CP guarantees that the prediction set will include the true label with a specified confidence level regardless of the underlying model's quality.

Conformal prediction (CP) is a machine learning framework for uncertainty quantification that produces statistically valid prediction regions (prediction intervals) for any underlying point predictor (whether statistical, machine, or deep learning) only assuming exchangeability of the data. CP works by computing nonconformity scores on previously labeled data, and using these to create prediction sets on a new (unlabeled) test data point.


The goal of standard classification algorithms is to classify a test object into one of several discrete classes. Conformal classifiers instead compute and output the p-value for each available class by performing a ranking of the nonconformity measure (α-value) of the test object against examples from the training data set.

Therefore even when an ML model is very accurate, CP provides calibrated prediction intervals or sets, making the predictions more interpretable and reliable for each test instance. In critical applications such as healthcare, finance, and autonomous driving, CP becomes valuable.

The key point, which you make, +1, is that the OP's question is misformed. The point of CP is to calculate prediction intervals or prediction sets. If "the original prediction was 95% accurate", then this refers to a point prediction, which is a different thing than PIs or PSs. BTW, forecasters, who have argued for many years for the conceptual advantages of PIs over point predictions, have been a little bemused at the hype about CP. (And skeptical about the key exchangeability condition.)

@StephanKolassa Well, that's a good summary of the answer. But then, why don't they just call it a new condition for PIs (or confidence intervals CIs)? Since I started reading about CP, I couldn't see any difference between constructing a CP and constructing a $1-\alpha$ CI.

@Con, CIs and PIs are not interchangeable. CI is for a parameter, PI is for a realization of a random variable.

@Con: Richard Hardy already pointed out the key difference between a PI and a CI; these are frequently confused but very different. CP is a way to calculate PIs (in a numerical prediction task; for classification, CP calculates PSs). Forecasters have long advocated the use of PIs in addition to point forecasts. (In my line of work, forecasting for replenishment, quantile forecasts or PIs are arguably all we care about; point forecasts are not very useful.) ...

... And CPs are just one more tool to calculate PIs. There are other ways to do so, most importantly using distributional assumptions on observations, or in a distribution-free way by resampling either in-sampling residuals or holdout forecast errors - which is pretty much what CP does, but which used to be considered only a detail in forecasting papers. So: by all means include PIs in your forecasting workflow to inform the subsequent decision, and do consider CP to calculate PIs, or use any other method that works in your specific case.

As to "why don't they just call it a new condition for PIs": I don't know. My best guess would be that the people who introduced CP were not conversant with the forecasting literature or community, and to a degree re-invented the wheel. That's not a problem, people do that all the time. (I once re-invented a very lovely wheel, which was gently pointed out to me by one of the big names in the field, Tilmann Gneiting. I still managed to salvage the publication, and it turned out better after Tilmann's feedback.)
